# How functions are mapped to correct filename in python packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example in `requests` library we have `get` method which is defined inside `api.py` file
but i can directly call it with `requests.get` .

as per my understanding it should be called like this `requests.api.get`

How python modules handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct that the name should be `requests.api.get`. In fact, if you look at `requests.get.__module__`, you will find that it is `requests.api`. Similarly, `requests.get.__globals__` is a reference to `requests.api.__dict__`.

Many libraries will export functions defined elsewhere through the top level namespace. This is usually done with an import like `from .api import get` in the `__init__.py` file of `requests`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing `import requests` the file `requests/__init__.py` is imported and when you access its content with dot notation like `requests.get` you in fact are accessing `requests.__init__.get`. This contains the following [line](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py#L115):

```
from .api import request, get, head, post, patch, put, delete, options
```

So this `__init__` file has `get` name in its scope, thats all. More info about `__init__.py` file here: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).